# How to create the split 1/2 login screen in vue such that one side contains fields and the other side is image?

Tags: vue.js

https://vuestic.epicmax.co/#/auth/login
I want something which looks as if in above link.

Comment: Are you using Vuetify / vue-material / any framework? Please provide more details about what you're using. If it's just pure HTML it's just CSS changes, with Vuetify you'll be able to use their grid system.

Comment: I was using Vuetify.

Comment: I just need a template for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using Vuetify you can use the container, layout and flex columns to create that:

```
<v-container>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <!-- xs12 and sm12 to make it responsive = 12 columns on mobile and 6 columns from medium to XL layouts -->
      <v-flex xs12 sm12 md6>
        <!-- Login form here -->
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm12 md6>
        <!-- artwork here -->
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
```

Check more details about how to use the grid system here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid

Comment: Is there any property to give height for flex.

Comment: You can use `fill-height` on the  `row` check more details and the "Layout Playground" here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid